# printing each component of a column shell script

Tags: shell, awk, text-files

I have a text file vis.degrib which looks like this:

```
Wahu,Campos,California,Egypt,Parity,London,New York,Berlin,Washington
40,56,120,110,90,50,55,67,78
56,54,100,110,75,45,65,55,60
```

I am trying to make a shell script that would print the following output:

```
Wahu
Campos
California
Egypt
Parity
London
New York
Berlin
Washington
```

That is just printing the first row and but have x loop through each column of the first row and print to output that column x (columns are separated by ,).

Below is a sample of the program:

```
#!/bin/bash
VIS_LOCNAMES=""
INPUT=vis.degrib
linecount=0
while read line
do
    echo "SFH-LINE:"
    echo ". $linecount ."
    echo ". $line ."
    if [ $linecount == 0 ];
    then
        VIS_LOCNAMES=$line
    fi
    let linecount++
done < $INPUT

echo ""
echo ""
echo "Locations are $VIS_LOCNAMES"

LOC_NUMBER=`echo $VIS_LOCNAMES | awk '{print NF}'`

while [[ x -le $LOC_NUMBER ]];
do
    echo "$x"
    echo "--------------------------"
    echo $VIS_LOCNAMES | awk 'FS="," {print $x}'
    let x++
done
```

I also eventually want to use a series of files based on the locations specified on the first row of the files that I mentioned. For instance I want to create "Egypt,csv, Wahu,csv, etc." That is why I want to be able to have x loop through the location columns in the first row. I eventually will be setting it up so that $file=`echo $VIS_LOCNAMES | awk 'FS="," {num=$x;print $num}'. I need help with getting this portion of code tweaked to give me the result I am looking for.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I also eventually want to use a series of files based on the locations specified on the first row of the files that I mentioned.  For instance I want to create "Egypt,csv, Wahu,csv, etc."  That is why I want to be able to have x loop through the location columns in the first row.     I eventually will be setting it up so that $file=`echo $VIS_LOCNAMES | awk 'FS="," {num=$x;print $num}'.  I need help with getting this portion of code tweaked to give me the result I am looking for.

Comment: Don't extend your question in a comment. Post the **full** question in the question.

Comment: I'm not an English teacher, but I'm also not clairvoyant, so I have no idea what the following is supposed to mean: "That is just printing the first row and but have x loop through each column of the first row and print to output that column x "  Can you rephrase that to be coherent?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative

```
head -1 <vis.degrib | tr ',' '\n'
```

if you want to create files with file names from header, awk might be a better alternative

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "" > $i".csv"}'
```

will create empty files for each header field, be careful though since there is no sanitization of file names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). It matches first line with `1`, replaces all commas with newlines, print them all and exit.

```
sed -n '1 { s/,/\n/g; p; q }' infile
```

It yields:

```
Wahu
Campos
California
Egypt
Parity
London
New York
Berlin
Washington
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F , -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1;print;exit}' vis.degrib
```

- `-F ,` split on `,`
- `-v OFS='\n'` use newline as the new field separator
- `$1=$1` force awk to split and recombine the input line (canonically I believe this should be `$0=$0` I think but that doesn't seem to work for some reason)
- `print` the re-combined line
- `exit` since we only want to print the first line